# TYPO3 Extbase: Save titles sorted in frontend (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a table
tx_bla_domain_model_offer

in the title field I store several titles from
tx_bla_domain_model_blubtitle
with
tx_bla_blub_title_mm

The first time I save everything is correct, I can sort the titles as I want and it keeps everything sorted.

Only, if I want to sort the same titles differently, it keeps the old sorting when saving...

Sorting in $_POST['tx_bla']['offer']['offerTitle'] is correct.
Sorting in $this->arguments->getArgument('offer')->getValue()->getOfferTitle() is not correct.

In tx_bla_blub_title_mm the sorting does not change...

In the TCA is set foreign_sortby, but it haves no effect...

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the `attention` section at [foreign_sortby](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline/Properties/ForeignSortby.html?highlight=foreign_sortby#foreign-sortby)?

Probably you want to use [foreign_default_sortby](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline/Properties/ForeignDefaultSortby.html#foreign-default-sortby)

Comment: I have tried both. Everything works fine in the backend, but not in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is create a empty Object and add the new titles.

```
    $offer->setOfferTitle(new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage);
    foreach ($_POST['tx_bla_jobs']['offer']['offerTitle'] as $titleUid) {
        $offer->addOfferTitle($this->offertitleRepository->findByUid($titleUid));
    }
```